# Merging mulitple rows to one row of a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Current dataframe was like below,

```
              0           1         2
0  HA-567034786  AB-1018724      None
1    AB-6348403  HA-7298656      None
```

After using the `apply()`, I just make it like,

```
def make_dict(row):
    s = set(x for x in row if x)
    return {x: list(s - {x}) for x in s}

result = df.apply(make_dict, axis=1).to_frame(name = 'duplicates')

                                duplicates
1    {'HA-567034786': ['AB-1018724'],'AB-1018724':['HA-567034786']}                                                                            
2    {'AB-6348403': ['HA-7298656'],'HA-7298656':['AB-6348403']}
```

Now I'm stucked on to make it a single dimentional dictionary like below,

```
{
  'HA-567034786': ['AB-1018724'],'AB-1018724':['HA-567034786'],
  'AB-6348403': ['HA-7298656'],'HA-7298656':['AB-6348403']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `apply` use dictionary comprehension with flattening:

```
print (df)
              0           1
0  HA-567034786  AB-1018724
1    AB-6348403  HA-7298656

def make_dict(row):
    s = set(x for x in row if x)
    return {x: list(s - {x}) for x in s}

result = {k:v for x in df.values for k, v in make_dict(x).items()}

print (result)
{'HA-567034786': ['AB-1018724'],
 'AB-1018724': ['HA-567034786'], 
 'HA-7298656': ['AB-6348403'],
 'AB-6348403': ['HA-7298656']}
```

Another solution with `apply`:

```
result = {k:v for x in df.apply(make_dict, axis=1) for k, v in x.items()}
```

Comment: You're a star mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [collections.ChainMap()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to group all the dictionaries to one as:

```
from collections import ChainMap
res =dict(ChainMap(*result['duplicates']))
```